# JavaScript сложить строки как числа

Tags: javascript

```
<select class='one'>
  <option value="2">1</option>
  <option value="10">2</option>
</select>
<select class='two'>
  <option value="20">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
</select>
<p class="result"></p>
<button class="btn">Считать</button>
<script>
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let one = document.querySelector('.one').value,
    two = document.querySelector('.two').value,
    res = document.querySelector('.result');
  res.innerHTML = eval(two + one);
});
</script>
```

Получается он берет c value значения как строки. Подскажите как вывести результат подсчитав их как числа. Можно ли вообще так брать значения option с select как я?

Comment: Да, Вы почти всё правильно делаете, просто проставьте  плюсы перед значениями. Таким образом они будут приведены к числу. `+two + +one` Но не забывайте, что вы берёте значение, которое установлено в `value` `options`

Comment: Спасибо работает)